# Android App - Crash Stack Trace on Play Console doesn't show correct method line numbers

Tags: android, google-play-console

It seems that a couple years ago before I started 'Generate Signed Bundles' for upload of my App to Google Play Store, that stack traces on the Play Console would show valid line numbers for where the error occurred in my code. But since then, I get invalid line numbers as such:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4035)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4201)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2438)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8663)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:567)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1135)
Caused by java.lang.NumberFormatException:
  at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString (FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
  at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble (FloatingDecimal.java:110)
  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble (Double.java:538)

  at com.-mydom-.mobile.Submit.onCreate (Submit.java:2)

  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8290)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8270)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1329)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4009)
```

In the line above

```
at com.-mydom-.mobile.Submit.onCreate (Submit.java:2)
```

Submit.onCreate starts at line number 103 and goes to 265. So, 'Submit.java:2' doesn't help me in any way that I know how to use.

How do I get back valid line numbers to improve my stack traces and debugging ability?

I have looked through a number of posts in stackoverflow and at Android docs and find things such as 'deobfuscation', but admit to simply being overwhelmed - as usual - with all the options (I don't know which branch of which option to pursue) and implementation details.

App size is not a concern. It is a very small app, so if I need to increase the size of my app to improve the info captured and optimize my ability to quickly analyze and correct bugs from the stack trace in the Play Console, I will gladly do that.

Update: here is what I find in my build.gradle concerning proguard.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rou have R8 enabled you should uncomment this lines

```
# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```

Comment: Thanks @logancodemaker! All new to me. I found proguard-rules.pro which has these settings commented in them. I uncomment them. Very ambiguous that -renamesourcefileattribute is what I am wanting. It seems that this will remove the source file name 'Submit.java' in this case, which I want. I went to the link in the file at developer.android.com... to read about the details of this. My brain is swimming after the first of a couple dozen large pages of information.

Comment: As for whether 'I have R8 enabled', I am not sure how to answer that. I looked for Settings and for text of 'R8' anywhere in my project and find nothing. I have included lines from my build.gradle file referencing proguard. I have uncommented the lines you specify above and will build anew and see what changes. I will certainly update here. If I search of "Android Studio Do I have R8 enabled" I find that "R8 is always used, unless you add android.enableR8=false in gradle.properties." So, I assume the answer to your question is YES.

Comment: R8 is a code obsfuscation mechanisme that prevent others people to reverse engineering your app in production. To enable R8 you just need to edit `build.gradle`, enable minification and ressource shrinking at `buildTypes` `release` 

`minifyEnabled true`
`shrinkResources true`

Comment: Ok - confirmed. The changes you stated above provided me with a valid code line number. " ... at com.-mydom-.mobile.Submit.onCreate (Submit.java:129)"!! Thanks. Marking this as answer.